# Reporting Services problem. Forward dependencies are not valid

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset, dependencies, multivalue

I have a problem with a Reporting Services report. My report has two datasets, one that fetches the actual report data and one that fetches translated resource strings for displaying wherever literal text is used on the report. This dataset requires three parameters, a language set id, a language code and a string to match against resource names.

Following an example I found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/a7d59224-0ee5-491e-883b-2e5fcb3edeab) (the reply by Miguel Catalão) I have created a multivalue parameter @Resources that will be populated from the resource dataset and a code function that looks up specific values from the multivalue query. This function will then be called from expressions wherever literal strings are used.

I think that this should work but I have run into a problem that I can't quite figure out a workaround for. There is a dependency problem in the @Resources parameter being dependent on the Resources dataset which in turn is dependent on three parameters; @LanguageSetID, @LanguageCode and @ResourceNameLookup. I have read that the order of declaring parameters is important so I have made sure that the last three parameters appear above the @Resources one and that all three of them have default values that will result in data being retrieved by the dataset.

Yet I am still getting the following errors when previewing the report; any advice or guidance would be most appreciated.

```
The report parameter ‘Resources’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter “LanguageCode”. Forward dependencies are not valid.
The report parameter ‘Resources’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter “ResourceNameLookup”. Forward dependencies are not valid.
```

Comment: Odd that you're not getting 3 errors back, no? What is different about the 3rd parameter 'LanguageSetID' that it is working ok?

Comment: It turns out that this was caused by my forgetting to change the type of the function argument from integer to string. Why that would cause the errors it did is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all caused by a stupid error I made. I copied and modified the code function from the post I mention but neglected to change the data type of the argument from integer to string, which mine is.

It seems rather odd that the error manifested in the way it did but I have gotten past that problem now, only to run into another that I ask about in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594978/reporting-services-multi-value-parameter-problem).

Comment: But what if you only have one parameter? My problem is the same, but I only have one parameter that should be populated from a dataset that does not run with any parameters (to build a list) and the value selected from the dropdown list *is* the parameter for other datasets in my report? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but it was due to something else.  What I had done was created a Parameter in my report, then linked the Default Values to a Dataset.

This in turn added the parameters needed in the Dataset.  Somehow, the order of the parameters in my list were changed.  This is when I stared getting the 'Forward Dependencies are not Valid' error.

I then looked at another report that used the same process to link a Parameter to a Dataset.  I noticed that the order of my Parameters were different.  I simply went back to my new report, and used the up and down arrows until my Parameters were in the same order as the working report.  This seemed to fix the error and work fine.  Apparently the the Parameter that was using the Dataset needs to be below the Parameters that are used in the SPROC.

I this helps someone in the long run.

C/N: Parameter was being filled by a Dataset(Stored Procedure). The Parameter that was being filled was above some of the Parameters that it was expecting for the SPROC.